# Is a probability density function always smooth?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Can you think of counter examples of a density that is continuous, but not smooth?

Comment: I should say -- only interested in continuous random variables.

Comment: Then please edit you question to say that, and while editing your question, please add why this question is important to you?  In what course are you studying this, or from what textbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about
$$ f(x) = \left\{
   \begin{align}
   & 0     && \text{if } |x| \geq 1\\
   & 1 + x && \text{if } -1 < x \leq 0\\
   & 1 - x && \text{if } 0 < x < 1
   \end{align}
\right. $$

It is continuous, but $ f'(x) $ is undefined at $x = -1$, $x = 0$ and $x = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is an entire class of continuous everywhere but nowhere differentiable functions; e.g., the [Takagi function](https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Elagarias//TALK-SLIDES/jmm-neworleans2011jan.pdf), easily extended to the entire real line.  The area under the curve is finite, so we can trivially convert it to a proper density on $[0,1]$ and again extend it to all of $\mathbb R$ by normalizing copies on $[k, k+1)$ for all $k \in \mathbb Z$ in a geometrically decreasing fashion.  Such a density would represent a real-valued continuous random variable that is nowhere differentiable.

See also the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve) article that calls this the "blancmange function."